# How to specify space between each list item and space before/after the whole list

Tags: microsoft-word, list

In word I want to specify the space between list items and the space before and after the whole list and it does not seem possible. Is there a way?

I do not want to alter the line spacing of the list as the list has multi-line list items and there needs to be a bigger gap between each list item than between a list items multiple lines.

The option:

> Paragraph > Indents and Spacing > Don't add space between paragraphs
>   of the same style

does not help me as it creates space between the lists but does not allow a thicker space before/after the list.

```
Paragraph Normal Text text text text text text text text...
...text text text text text text text.
<Spacing before List Paragraph>
    List Item 1 Line 1
    List Item 1 Line 2
<Space between list item>
    List Item 2 Line 1
    List Item 2 Line 2
<Space between list item>
    List Item 3 Line 1
    List Item 3 Line 2
<Spacing after List Paragraph>
Paragraph Normal Text text text text text text text text...
...text text text text text text text.
```

It basically needs to look like this with the three distances required shown:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never found a way to do that with Word styles or styles in most publishing software, because paragraph styles do not usually have a way to specify or target "entire list." This is assuming we're not talking about HTML, which has UL and LI elements that can be targeted.

These are the common workarounds for styles. This applies to almost any text layout software:

- Create "bu1" and "bulast" styles that you apply to the first and last bullet items in lists. These can have the unique space before and after settings that you want to see.
- Create "before list" and "after list" paragraph styles, and apply these to blank paragraphs before and after every list.

Comment: Or jmanually adjust the space above and below the bullet list.